# Wrap a runtime generated delegate in a factory and pass the invocation result as a parameter

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

Hopefully the following example will explain the problem better than the title :/

Suppose we have a `Calculator` class that allows different functions to be registered:

```
public class Calculator
{
    public void RegisterFunction(string functionName, Func<int, int, int> function)
    {
        functions.Add(functionName, function);
    }

    public int Calculate(string functionName, int x, int y)
    {
        Func<int, int, int> function;

        if (functions.TryGetValue(functionName, out function))
        {
            return function(x, y);
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("No function is registered with name " + functionName);
    }
}
```

We can then register an "addition" function by providing an inline delegate:

```
calculator.RegisterFunction("add", (x, y) => x + y);
Console.WriteLine(calculator.Calculate("add", 2, 3));
```

However, to make our calculator easier to extend and to support complex functions, we provide an interface with the same signature as the inline delegate:

```
public interface ICalculatorFunction
{
    int Execute(int x, int y);
}
```

We can create an extension method for `Calculator` that makes it easy to register `ICalculatorFunction` instances:

```
public static void RegisterFunction<TFunction>(this Calculator calculator, TFunction function) where TFunction : ICalculatorFunction
{
    calculator.RegisterFunction(typeof(TFunction).Name, function.Execute);
}
```

Registration:

```
calculator.RegisterFunction(new Multiply());
```

However, here we are passing an instance and really we would like to only create the function instance when we need to perform the calculation. We can support this by passing in a "function factory":

```
public static void RegisterFunction<TFunction>(this Calculator calculator, Func<TFunction> factory) where TFunction : ICalculatorFunction
{
    calculator.RegisterFunction(typeof(TFunction).Name, (x, y) => factory().Execute(x, y));
}
```

Here we provide an inline delegate that first invokes the factory and then calls `Execute` on the created `ICalculatorFunction` instance.

Registration:

```
calculator.RegisterFunction(() => new Subtract());
```

#### The Problem

All of the above examples work fine when the function type is known at compile time. However, we need to support passing in a calculator function `Type` and invoking the same `Register` method on a `Calculator` instance.

So far I've only been able to achieve creating the `ICalculatorFunction` instance in advance, using `Delegate.CreateDelegate` to then pass a reference to it's `Execute` function to the `Calculator`:

```
public static void RegisterFunction(this Calculator calculator, Type functionType, Func<Type, object> factory)
{
    var delegateType = typeof(Func<,,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int), typeof(int), typeof(int));
    var funcDelegate = (Func<int, int, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, factory(functionType), "Execute");

    var registerMethod = calculator.GetType().GetMethod("RegisterFunction", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
    registerMethod.Invoke(calculator, new object[] { functionType.Name, funcDelegate });
}
```

Registration:

```
calculator.RegisterFunction(typeof(Subtract), type => Activator.CreateInstance(type));
```

However, the `funcDelegate` I pass to `Calculator.RegisterFunction` needs to effectively do the same as our generic extension i.e. `(x, y) => factory().Execute(x, y)`.

Unfortunately this is where my Reflection skills fail me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a generic class to store you generic delegate instead of using generic method.

You can delegate call to generic method to you method in your generic type.